# Would it make sense to copy (some) tag wikis from SO?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lot of good tag wikis on SO and some of these tags apply to CR as well. So I was wondering if it would make sense to copy them from SO? I guess the excerpt might be different to state why or which questions should be tagged as such in the context of CR but the tag wiki could easily be the same.

Any opinions?

**Update** for clarification:

I am not referring to copying over all tags from SO. I am referring to copying the tag wiki content for tags which also exist on SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A number of suggested edits came through recently where the suggester was doing exactly that... by this user... [verdammelt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10384/verdammelt?tab=activity&sort=revisions). I think this is a good idea (and I [have done it myself](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/39051/revisions)), but with the following clarifications:

- All data in the copied text should be fact-checked, this includes:

  1. all external links should still exist
  2. any references to other tags should also still exist (SO has many more tags than CR)
- Only copy content where it makes sense, just because both SO and CR have the same tag, it does not mean that the tags should have the same purpose/description on both
- Some tags are not high-value tags anyway, and should be discouraged... consider requesting the tagged questions are re-tagged, or the tag removed... adding a comprehensive wiki to a 'bad' tag is not necessarily a good solution.

Essentially, use your head still, and only if the SO tag text has the same meaning, and is appropriate, should it be copied to CR.

Comment: It's also important to note any differences in site policies.  For instance, if a tag refers to broken code, that part either needs to be revised or not include.